# Trying to simplify Karnaugh Map with only four groups of "True" Indicators

Tags: boolean-logic, truthtable, karnaugh-map

In the included screenshot, I am trying to derive the simplest boolean function.  I used these four groups of ones to derive the different variable groups.  According to the solution in my book, I don't have the correct four groups, but it does seem to be a grouping of four and not five.  Does anyone see a grouping scenario I might have missed?  I tried wrapping around but that doesn't seem to help either.

[image]

My final function of w, x, y, z was the following and it is apparently not the solution:

F (w, x, y, z) = w'x'z + w'yz' + xy' + wz

[karnaugh map with my grouping of 1s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGK7F.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is

```
F(w, x, y, z) = x y'  + w z + x' z + w' y z'
```

Your term `w'x'z` can be slimmed down (or merged) to `x'z` as a disjunction of `w'x'z` and `wx'z`.

Comment: Thank you @Axel Kemper.  When I looked up disjunction, I wasn't a hundred percent sure if I got it.  If I were to put it in my own terms, could I say that we can merge w'x'z to wx'z and in this scenario that w and w' cancel each other out?

Actually that doesn't make sense.  Let me see if I can do some research on this term "disjunction."

Comment: Replace disjunction by logical or.

Comment: I actually ended up finding this afterwards! But still, thank you for that clarification!